# Error Copying Data From S3 to AWS Redshift With Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

While executing a COPY command utilizing psycopg2, I receive the error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: unterminated quoted string at or near "'"
LINE 12:    NULL as '
```

Here is my origianl query:

```
"""copy dcm_floodlight_raw_abg_stg (COLUMN_NAMES)
from 'S3_BUCKET_PATH'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=KEY;aws_secret_access_key=SECRET'
gzip
DELIMITER '\t'
DATEFORMAT as 'yyyy-mm-dd'
BLANKSASNULL 
TRUNCATECOLUMNS 
FILLRECORD
MAXERROR 100
ACCEPTINVCHARS as '?'
NULL as '\0';"""
```

Not too sure why I am receiving this error as it doesn't throw this error for any other single quotations.

Comment: I wonder if you application is interpreting `\0` before it gets into the string? Does it work with `NULL as '\\0'`?

Comment: worked perfectly! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When having issues with a query you can use the [psycopg2 mogrify function](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify) to see if there is an issue with your string. It will attempt to interpolate any parameters as well so can be a good check. Since I didn't have a cursor object to call it on I did this instead:

```
print psycopg2.extensions.adapt(YOUR_QUERY).getquoted()
```

In your case this gives:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> print psycopg2.extensions.adapt(YOUR_QUERY).getquoted()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters.

>>> print psycopg2.extensions.adapt('\\0').getquoted()
'\\0'
>>>
```

So you can see it doesn't like the `'\0'`. If you escape the backslash as John Rotenstein suggests psycopg2 will accept the query but it may not give you what you want for your null value. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-null-as) suggests it should work if you can get the interpolation sorted out.